# get all spatial type points within radius in km with mariaDb, mySQL

Tags: mysql, geometry, mariadb, points, radius

Here is the problem,

Already made several researches about it, but did not find any clear and well explained solution about that. Some people are talking about functions like `st_distance` or `st_within` which refer to mysql/mariadb versions but these functions seem to have no real documentation and do not seem to fit my problem.

So what I'm tryin to do is :

Get ALL spatial POINTS `(lat,ln)` which are within a circle with a defined RADIUS in `KILOMETRES`.

User will give a radius, contained between 1 and 100 km, and will receive all database records that are within that radius.

"`point`s" table looks like this :

```
ID -- POINT -- SOMETEXT
```

Point is the spatial type point used in `mySql(>5.6) / mariaDb(5.5.40) (lat,lng)`

so, the query should look like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM points WHERE (function... to get distance) <= definedDistance"
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with what you wrote here:

> Some people are talking about functions like st_distance or st_within
>   which refer to mysql/mariadb versions but these functions seem to have
>   no real documentation and do not seem to fit my problem.

`st_distance` is [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) and seems to fit your problem very nicely.

See my example, where I'm looking for points inside a circle of radius 1 and center in (2, 2):

```
CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 3)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 4)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(3 3)'));
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(4 4)'));

SELECT AsText(g) from geom where ST_Distance(point(2,2), g) <= 1
```

Output:

```
POINT(1 2)
POINT(2 2)
```

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct. MagiaDB ST_Distance function looks like it calculates distance on a cartesian plane (ie. simple X, Y calculations, not latitude, longitude). In this case the function cannot be used for distances between GIS points. See the following;

Comment: `set @p1 = point (90,0);
 set @p2 = point (90,50);
 select ST_Distance(@p1, @p2);`

Distance should be 0 as both points are at the north pole. Function gives an answer of 50.

PS sorry about the multiple comments, I could not figure how to add code block.